# Tracking state in separate tabs in MVC 3 application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, state

Basically what I need to be able to do, and I already know it is not a good idea, I have fought tooth and nail to not do it, but I need to have it so each individual tab in tabbed browsers is treated as a separate session; users will need to be able to have the same page open in separate tabs, but in a different context.

I have spent countless hours working on this and come down to the fact that in order for this to work, you are going to have to have a key that you embed into a hidden field, or on the route, or something like that.

So with that said, do you have any good ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Shouldn't each instance of the same page have it's own Session associated with the server? You could keep track of each client by it's session id.

Comment: @mfanto - Not quite sure what you mean, but if you open a page on one tab and then open the same page in a new tab, they share the session.

Comment: Given that session state is by default associated by cookies, you will need to use cookieless sessions.

Comment: @SamStriano: I think you can use cookieless sessions, then each tab instance gets it's own session id. But that doesn't seem like a good solution.